# Is possible to upgrade openssh-server OpenSSH_7.6p1, to OpenSSH_8.0p1?

Tags: server, 18.04, openssh

Tried to install OpenSSH_8.0p1 but installed OpenSSh Client only.

```
sudo apt install openssl-server Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package openssl-server
```

Comment: How did you "try to install"?

Comment: And why do you need 8.0. Ubuntu 18.04 has 1.7.6p1 with security updates.

Comment: PCI complaints fails due to openssh username enumeration vulnerability

Comment: What is PCI complaints?

Comment: you mistyped the command, it's `openssh-server` instead of `openssl-server`

Comment: @Pilot6 Payment card industry compliance

Comment: So were you able to upgarde openssh to OpenSSH8.0p1 on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Here are some [general instructions I wrote on SuperUser to upgrade to any version of openssh on Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/a/1763433/425838). In my example, I upgraded openssh 7.6p1 to 8.9p1.

Answer (score 20):

To upgrade OpenSSH from 7.6 to 8.9 on Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic), I followed the instructions given here: [How to Install OpenSSH 8.0 Server from Source in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/install-openssh-server-from-source-in-linux/).

The version I started with:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
```

Here are the commands to upgrade:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev
sudo mkdir /var/lib/sshd
sudo chmod -R 700 /var/lib/sshd/
sudo chown -R root:sys /var/lib/sshd/
wget -c https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-8.9p1.tar.gz
tar -xzf openssh-8.9p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-8.9p1/
sudo apt install libpam0g-dev libselinux1-dev libkrb5-dev
./configure --with-kerberos5 --with-md5-passwords --with-pam --with-selinux --with-privsep-path=/var/lib/sshd/ --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh
make
sudo make install
```

Restart your machine (without it the remote connections are using the old version).

#### Check new version

##### Locally

Open a new terminal and run:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

##### Remote

Check if the OpenSSH version has changed from a remote machine:

```
$ ssh -v user@ip
```

Look for a line saying `Remote protocol version`. It shows the version.

##### Online

Use [sshcheck.com](https://sshcheck.com/) to check the version.

Comment: My Ubuntu 18.04 LTS base install (`$ ssh -V : OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017`) gave warning after upgrade (to: `$ ssh -V : OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020`) with the mesage: "`/etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Unsupported option "gssapiauthentication"`" -> Kerberos missing, add `--with-kerberos5` to `./configure` line.

Comment: @hakre I then got an error "auth.h:40:18: fatal error: krb5.h: No such file or directory" - how did you solve this?

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea: The message sounds like the sources are missing, try to first `apt install libkrb5-dev` and then ./configure ... + make again (or only make as it should be already configured from last run).

Comment: `ssh -V`: "OpenSSH_8.5p1", `telnet the.host`: "OpenSSH_6.6.1p1". Since `init.d` script doesn't use `/usr/local/sbin`. How to properly replace distrib binary ?

Comment: When I get to the `make` step the output says "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop."  If I proceed, the upgrade doesn't work. `ssh -V` still shows the old version.

Comment: I'm looking at `--with-privsep-path=/var/lib/sshd/`. I do not have a `/var/lib/sshd/` path on my ubuntu system.  I'm concerned about pointing it there since it doesn't exist.  Is there a default that I can look up with the current version so I keep it the same as the current version?

Comment: For anyone who followed the steps and still find that the openssh version didn't change, check Andy's answer (i.e copy /usr/local/sbin/sshd to /usr/sbin/sshd  # after making a backup of the latter). Checkout your syslog for any errors related to configuration file when restarting service

Answer (score 4):

If you search with your apt tool on ubuntu repositories for your version typing `apt search openssh` you will find the package `openssh-server/ubuntu-codename version` in green among others packages unrelated to your question.

If this is the version you're looking for (mine shows openssh 1:8.0p11 already), you can install it with `sudo apt install openssh-server` as you would normally. However, if you can't find it on ubuntu repositories, you could search for it on official repos or even try to compile it from source code.

Edit: @VinohRc, I misstyped openssh, but edited the answer to the correct name. However,  as @Pilot6 said, ubuntu 18.04 still dont have 1.8 version.

Comment: **sudo apt install openssl-server**   
    Reading package lists... Done <br/>
    Building dependency tree       <br/>
    Reading state information... Done<br/>
    E: Unable to locate package openssl-server <br/>

Comment: You are using Ubuntu 19.10 that has the 1.8.0 version, but 18.04 is still on 1.7.6.

Comment: @VinothRc You probably don't use multiverse repo.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Also refer to the [above answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259631/618353). I am using Ubuntu 16.x and although `ssh -V` shows the correct version, `telnet` keeps showing the old one. After a short search, I found that the `sshd` service keeps the old version, so I did the following:

```py
sudo cd /usr/sbin
sudo mv sshd sshd.bak                 # make a copy before overwriting
sudo cp /usr/local/sbin/sshd sshd
```

Using `telnet` should now respond with the updated version, but, for safety, a reboot of the server is recommended.

Comment: Directory: /usr/sbin/
Commands: 
`mv sshd sshd.bak`
`cp /usr/local/sbin/sshd sshd`

works for me

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 20,
check your current SSH version;

```
ssh -V
```

Then, if you need an upgrade;

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev
sudo mkdir /var/lib/sshd
sudo chmod -R 700 /var/lib/sshd/
sudo chown -R root:sys /var/lib/sshd/
wget -c https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-8.8p1.tar.gz
```

You can find all versions [here](https://www.openssh.com/portable.html#http).

Then,

```
tar -xzf openssh-8.8p1.tar.gz
cd openssh-8.8p1/
sudo apt install libpam0g-dev libselinux1-dev libkrb5-dev
./configure --with-kerberos5 --with-md5-passwords --with-pam --with-selinux --with-privsep-path=/var/lib/sshd/ --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh
make
sudo make install
```

Check your upgraded version;

```
ssh -V

OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

If it still shows the old version then copy the new version as below.

```
sudo cd /usr/sbin
sudo mv sshd sshd.bak                 # Back up existing
sudo cp /usr/local/sbin/sshd sshd
```